# Why is the following algorithm for K-CLIQUE not in NL?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, turing-machines, np-complete

It's known that K-CLIQUE is a NP-Complete problem.

The question is, what am I missing in the following non-deterministic algorithm, which should decide the K-CLIQUE problem in O(logn) space.

(It must be wrong, otherwise K-CLIQUE which is proven to be NP-Complete would be in NL, therefore NP=NL, and that's not proven.)

> **1)** Guess a vertex - x, (as a delegate for the potential K-group of
>    vertices).
>   **2)** Verify that x has at most k neighbor vertices
>   **2.1)** Otherwise, return F
>   **3)** For each neighbor x'
>   **3.1)** For each neighbor x''
>   **3.1.1)** Verify that the edge (x', x'') exists.
>   **3.1.1.1)** Otherwise, return F
>   **4)** return T

*Complexity:*

**1)** The delegate x is encoded with O(logn) space.
**2)** In each iteration only x and one of his neighbors are on the working tape - 2logn -> O(logn).
(The validation if an edge exists is done by reading the input tape and shouldn't affect the overall space complexity)
**3)** In order to iterate over the neighbors of x, only 2 'pointers' to E are needed. - O(logn), plus the verification is again reading the input tape and shouldn't affect the overall complexity.

What's wrong with the analysis above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step 2 is not right: $x$ could belong to a clique of size $k$ but have more than $k - 1$ neighbours. To find a clique of size $k$ containing $x$ you need to search through all subsets of size $k - 1$ of the neighbours of $x$.

Comment: I see, which requires to keep track of all the k-1 neighbors. (In that case, if k=n, the problem is no longer solvable in O(logn) space). Thanks!